# Is there a way to count character frequency with an ArrayList similar to a regular array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Usually when you want to get the frequency of a character you can do something like this:

```
int[] count = new int[256];
for(int i: arr) count[arr.charAt(i)]++;
// Example if you have 2 'a' characters count[97] (97 being the ascii value of 'a') will return 2
```

Is there a way to do this with an ArrayList instead?

Comment: Sure, you can, but there wouldn’t be much benefit to it. It would be more verbose, and use memory and CPU less efficiently. The usual reasons to use an `ArrayList` (such as the ability to resize) don’t apply. Can you elaborate the question to explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Let's go nuts with the following code, or read on further below for simpler code.

```java
"Hello"
        .codePoints()       // Returns `IntStream` of the code point for each character in the string.
        .boxed()            // Converts `int` primitives to `Integer` objects.
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity() ,   // Classification function.
                        TreeMap :: new ,        // Map factory.
                        Collectors.counting()   // Downstream collector.
                )
        )
        .forEach(
                ( codePoint , count ) ->
                        System.out.println( "Code point: " + codePoint + " | Character: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) + " | Count: " + count )
        );
```

```
Code point: 72 | Character: H | Count: 1
Code point: 101 | Character: e | Count: 1
Code point: 108 | Character: l | Count: 2
Code point: 111 | Character: o | Count: 1
Code point: 128075 | Character:  | Count: 1
```

## List

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360050/is-there-a-way-to-count-character-frequency-with-an-arraylist-similar-to-a-regul#comment124375902_70360050), you could use a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`. But likely no benefit. The code would be more complicated, would use more memory, and would likely be less performant. You would have to use `Integer` objects rather than `int` primitives.

By the way, you should not be using `char`. That type has been legacy since Java 2. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

And your limit of 256 is far too small. Java supports all of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode.  Those characters are assigned to code point integer numbers ranging over a million. Use the constant `Character.MAX_CODE_POINT` as your limit.

```
List< Integer > counts = new ArrayList<>( Character.MAX_CODE_POINT ) ;
```

Populate with a zero for each element. A list is initialized with null in each element, unlike an array of `int` being initialized to zero in each element.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT ; i ++ ) 
{
    counts.add( 0 ) ;  
}
```

Process your input.

```
String input = "Hello" ; 
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray() ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < codePoints.length ; i ++ ) 
{
    int codePoint = codePoints[ i ] ;
    int count = counts.get( codePoint ) ;
    counts.set( codePoint , count + 1 ) ;
}
```

We could report the results by dumping `counts` list to the console. But with over a million elements, that would be cumbersome. Instead, let's filter out all the elements where the count is zero.

```java
for ( int index = 0 ; index < counts.size() ; index++ )
{
    if ( counts.get( index ) != 0 )
    {
        System.out.println(
                index + " ➣ " + counts.get( index )
        );
    }
}
```

Or, do the same using streams and lambda syntax. Save effect.

```java
IntStream.range( 0 , counts.size() )
        .filter( index -> counts.get( index ) != 0 )
        .mapToObj( index -> index + " ➣ " + counts.get( index ) )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );
```

When run:

```
72 ➣ 1
101 ➣ 1
108 ➣ 2
111 ➣ 1
128075 ➣ 1
```

## Map

If using objects and collections, using a `Map` instead of a `List` would make much more sense. You would have only as many entries in the map as you have distinct letters in your input, rather than over a million in your list.

A map tracks pairs of key and value. In our problem at hand, we would use the code point number as our key, and the count would be our value.

And if we would want to keep our keys, our code points, in order we would use a `NavigableMap`.

```java
String input = "Hello";

NavigableMap < Integer, Long > codePointFrequency =
        input
                .codePoints()                       // Returns `IntStream` of the code point for each character in the string.
                .boxed()                            // Converts `int` primitives to `Integer` objects.
                .collect(                           
                        Collectors.groupingBy( 
                            Function.identity() ,   // Classification function.
                            TreeMap :: new ,        // Map factory.
                            Collectors.counting()   // Downstream collector. 
                        )
                );
```

Dump the map to console.

```java
System.out.println( "codePointFrequency = " + codePointFrequency );
```

When run.

```
codePointFrequency = {72=1, 101=1, 108=2, 111=1, 128075=1}
```

Report each character.

```java
codePointFrequency.forEach(
        ( codePoint , count ) ->
                System.out.println( "Code point: " + codePoint + " | Character: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) + " | Count: " + count )
);
```

When run.

```
Code point: 72 | Character: H | Count: 1
Code point: 101 | Character: e | Count: 1
Code point: 108 | Character: l | Count: 2
Code point: 111 | Character: o | Count: 1
Code point: 128075 | Character:  | Count: 1
```

Comment: Initialize the list in one step: `List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>(Collections .nCopies(Character.MAX_CODE_POINT, 0));`

Comment: @英語は苦手 or even better `counts.set(codePoint, count + 1) ;`